# A simple GUI with pyQT does not work. Why?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have written the following python pyQT code to run a simple dialog application. However that does not work.

I'm using PyQT 5.0 on Win 8 64BIT.

It simply does not work and no error is returned.

When I run it, the current IDE (which is pycharm) gets blurred (which happens when a new windows is shown generally), though, no window is shown, and when I stop the execution, it returns -1. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ *
from sys import *
from math import *
from PyQT5.QtCore import *
from PyQT5.QtGui import *
from PyQT5.QtWidgets import *

class Form (QGuiDialog) :
    def __init__(self, parent=None) :
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an Expression, then Press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updateGui)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")
    def updateGui (self) :
        try :
            text = unicode(self.lineedit.txt())
            self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s<b>" % (text, eval(text)))
        except :
            self.browser.append("%s is an invalid expression" % (text))
app = QCoreApplication(sys.agrv)
x = Form()
x.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that PyQT5 does not support SIGNALs and SLOTS used in PyQT4.
Therefore I think you might try a different way instead of SIGNAL for your lineedit.
Instead of:

```
self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updateGui)
```

try

```
self.lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.updateGui)
```

Also I would suggest reading here the differences between PyQT5 and PyQT4 http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html
and check in the PyQT5 folder on your drive for extremely useful samples.

Comment: This is the right idea but textChanged will react as soon as you type - which doesn't appear to be the intent here. I used editingFinished instead and that gives what seems to be the right result

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code, I will address just some of them:

1. In order to actually see something with Qt you need to create a `QApplication` not a `QCoreApplication`.
2. You must fix the imports in the the line: `from __future__ *`.
3. On `updateGui` you need to initialize `text` if you want the exception handler to work fine.

Finally this is a working example of your code: 
**NOTE: I don't have PyQt5 just PyQt4, but I'm sure you'll get the idea ;)**

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form (QDialog) :
    def __init__(self, parent=None) :
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("Type an Expression, then Press Enter")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updateGui)
        self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")
    def updateGui(self):
        text = self.lineedit.text()
        self.lineedit.clear()
        try :
            text = unicode(text)
            self.browser.append("%s = <b>%s<b>" % (text, eval(text)))
        except :
            self.browser.append("<font color=red>%s</font> is an invalid expression" % (text))
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
x = Form()
x.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I just tested the example above (from @xndrme) and it is working..maybe you have something wrong in your path for Qt or python?..